# Intuition behind the Connecting Morphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-cohomology

I have seen that a s.e.s of $G$-modules

$$0\longrightarrow A \longrightarrow B\longrightarrow C \longrightarrow 0$$

gives rise to the following long exact sequence:

$$ 0 \rightarrow H^0(G,A) \rightarrow H^0(G,B) \rightarrow H^0(G,C) \rightarrow H^1(G,A) \rightarrow \ldots.$$
Here, we have a conneting morphism $\Delta: H^i(G,C) \rightarrow H^{i+1}(G,A).$
My question is: What does this connecting morphism do with the cocycles and coboundaries? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you know the snake lemma? because it is just the morphism from there, i.e. comes from nice diagram chase

Comment: Yes, I'm aware what the snake lemma is. I'm also aware how the connecting morphism is constructed.

Comment: I was just asking for some kind of supplementary motivation/intuition.

Comment: Have you already find an answer?